# UIView is being moved when changing height constraint on iphone 6/6 plus

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have an `UILabel` inside `UIView` inside an `UIscroll`. The text in the `UILabel` can change so I make this method to change the height constraint of it

```
func recalculateHeight(){
    l_info.sizeToFit();
    lc_heightInfo.constant = l_info.frame.height;
}
```

I am calling this method in the `viewDidLoad()` after calling `self.view.setNeedsLayout();` and `self.view.layoutIfNeeded();` to have the correct width depending on what iPhone the user is.

Everything works perfect on the iPhone 4s/5/5s but when trying it on iPhone 6/6 plus the view is moved.

This is how it looks on iPhone 5s:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx3om.png

And this is how it looks on iPhone 6/6 plus:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKf5T.png

I've being searching this for a while and haven't found anything similar.

**EDIT:**

The constraints are the following:

1. Between the top of `UIScrollView` and the top of `UIImageView`. **Value = 0**
2. Height of the `UIImageView`. **Value = 128**
3. Between the bottom of `UIImageView` and the top `UIView` containing the `UILabel`. **Value = 7**
4. Between the top `UIView` and top of the `UILabel`. **Value = 17**
5. Height of the `UILabel`. **This is the constraint I am changing**
6. Between the bottom of the `UILabel` and the bottom of the `UIView`. **Value = 17**
7. Between the bottom of the `UIView` and the bottom of the `UIScrollView`. **Value = 7**

**EDIT 2:**

I checked the constraint between the bottom of the `UIImageView` and the `UIView` (Number 3) and the debugger says it is setted to 7. I tried setting it from the code but nothing happened.

I also entered the view debbuger and there it looks perfect.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `l_info.frame.height` stays the same across devices but the header imageView height changes.

Check how you set the `lc_heightInfo` constraint. It should set be between the (labels) container view and the imageView you have on the top. This way your container view will always be same distance from the imageView on top.

Alternatively, if that ImageView is not a part of your scroll view, then you should set one constraint between container view and the top of the scroll view AND one for the top of the scrollView and the header ImageView. Hope this helps :)

Comment: The imageview is part of the scrollview. I will edit the post and put the constraints that are setted.